# App Update Issue show old version in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have built a Flutter app that is available on the Play Store, and some users have reported that even after updating the app on their devices, they continue to see the old version. The Play Store indicates that the updated version is available. I have also sent a separate APK file to address this issue, but they still experience the same problem.

I have update version from grade and pubspec.yaml